# how to design this security demands?

Tags: python, linux, security, ssh

A python program `P` running on server `S1`, listening port `8443`.
Some other services can send `id_isa, ip` pair to `P`. `P` could use this pair and make a ssh connection to the `ip` (create a ssh process).

How to make protect the `id_rsa` file even the machine `S1` is cracked ? How to let root user can't get the `id_rsa` content (It seems ssh can use `-i` keyfile only)?

The main problem is `P` must save the id_rsa file to the disk,so that ssh can use it to conect to the ip.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add an ssh-daemon on Port 8443 and use ssh-Agent forwarding?

That way the private key never gets written down on P and you don't have to write and maintain your own program.

Comment: because P does not just do forwarding,it runs some scripts with ssh (python/ansible).

Comment: So what is it you actually want to do? Do you need an interactive shell on the destination server (ip). Or do you want to execute a script that does something on the destination server via ansible?

In the latter case use a login on server S1 with a command only key. Your script (which is the ssh-command)  then reads the parameters from SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND and goes from there.